# An interior/closure Galois connection

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, terminology, order-theory, galois-connections

In *A Primer on Galois Connections*, the authors define a Galois connection thus (definition 1, p. 104).

> Consider posets $\mathcal{P} = \langle P, \leq\rangle$ and $\mathcal{Q} = \langle Q,\sqsubseteq\rangle$. If $P\overset{\pi_*}{\rightarrow} Q$ and $Q\overset{\pi^*}{\rightarrow} P$ are functions such that for all $p \in P$ and all $q \in Q$
>   $$
> p \leq \pi^*(q)\quad \text{iff}\quad \pi_*(p)\sqsubseteq q
> $$
>   then the quadruple $\pi = \langle\mathcal{P},\pi_*,\pi^*,\mathcal{Q}\rangle$ is called a *Galois connection*.

They follow this definition by a listing of various kinds of Galois connections. One of these kinds is as follows.

> We say that $\pi$ is [...] an *interior* (respectively, *closure*) *connection* if $\pi_*$ (respectively, $\pi^*$) is an inclusion.

What does 'inclusion' mean in this context? Does it mean [inclusion map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map)? In other words, is a Galois connection called *interior* if $P \subseteq Q$ and $\pi_*$ is the identity map?

---

ERNÉ M, KOSLOWSKI J, MELTON A, STRECKER G. A Primer on Galois Connections. Ann N Y Acad Sci. 1993; 103-125. doi:10.1111/j.1749-6632.1993.tb52513.x.

Comment: That could be it, or somewhat equivalently $\pi_*(p)\leq \pi_*(p') \iff p\leq p'$

Comment: The term *inclusion* would strictly imply that $P=Q$. (But the p.o.set relations may differ.) Is this the case in the context? Possibly the focus is on the partial orderings, not on the sets... Examples could make this clear.